# how to hide/unhide android app icon in .net maui?

Tags: c#, maui

I want to hide android app icon in .net maui but I did not find any way.

In android studio we can hide app with this code:

```cs
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

but how we can hide android app in maui?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide Android app icon"?

Comment: I mean hide android app that write by maui,when press a button we could hide it's icon from apps list.I write such code in androidstudio ,but in maui i need help.

Comment: Anything an Android app can do, can be put in code in project’s directory `Platforms/Android`. If you can’t figure out C# translation of some API such as `getPackageManager`, try search `Maui Xamarin Android getPackageManager`.

Comment: thnks a lot finally i fount api by your guide:Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.ComponentName, ComponentEnabledState.Disabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);